# Fibonacci sequence in RISC V using recursion

Tags: recursion, fibonacci, riscv

I am trying to write a recursive function in RISC-V where it calculates the Fibonacci sequence in RISC V of a number n, in this case n=7. So the expected answer of fib(n) where n=7 should be 13.

```
addi x10, x10, 7  
main:
    beq x10, x0, done 
    addi x5, x0, 1
    beq x10, x5, done 
    addi sp, sp -16 
    sd ra, 8(sp)
    sd x10, 0(sp)
    addi x10, x10, -1 
    jal x1, main
    ld x5, 0(sp)
    sd x10, 0(sp)
    addi x10, x5, -2
    jal x1, main
    ld x5, 8(sp)
done:
    add x10, x10, x5
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    ld ra, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 16
    li a7, 10
    ecall
```

I've managed to get this far and the code does run but it always prints out the value of 2. I would like to know why and what I need to change to print out the value of fib(n) which like I said n=7 so fib(7)=13 is the expected value. Where is my mistake in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your function fails to account for register collisions between different levels of the recursion.  You cannot put 2 different values in the same register without wiping out the former value with the latter.  Nothing in the hardware "stacks" register values, so if you want that behavior, you do it yourself using instructions to accomplish that.

---

Don't write a recursive `main`.  Your `main` should be a test case that either inputs a test value, then calls your recursive `fib` function (or calls with a hard-coded parameter), then prints out the results, then stops the process.

---

Never mix x register names like x10 with friendly register names, like a7; very confusing and super error prone.

If you want to write readable code use only the friendly register names, and don't use x register names at all (except perhaps x0).

---

The calling convention tells us what how to

- pass parameter, and
- receive return values registers

Which registers are

- scratch/call-clobbered, and,
- call-preserved, and how to preserve them

When one function calls another the convention should be observed (though optimizations are possible, one should learn the standard approach first).

Recursion adds no additional requirements to the calling convention — it is just one function calling another — that it is calling itself is just a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  All you have to do is the usual things required by the calling convention and the needs of your function, viewed as if it were calling something external rather than itself.

You can search for function calling for RISC V (or MIPS, very similar), to find lots of posts about how this is done.